# Django: How to get setUpTestData to run once for all tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

I am running django + django_tenants + django_restframework. In the mulit-tenant environment, there needs to be an instance in the tenants table for each schema - in my testing, that means "public", "test", and "test2".

Creating those tenants, and their corresponding schemas, need to be created for all tests.  The data in those instances will not change, so I want to do this once at the beginning of the test run, and not have it repeated again for the duration.

The things I've learned from my research:

- setUp() runs before each individual test
- setUpClass() runs before each test case
- setUpTestData() runs before each test case

The problem I've run into is, when my second set of tests run, I get exceptions when trying to create the tenants/schemas because they already exist.

I've also found setup_databases() in the Django advanced testing doc and am wondering if that is the place for this... i.e. can it be subclassed?

This is my base class that all tests subclass from...

```py
class TenantTestCase(APITestCase):
    public_tenant = None
    test_tenant   = None
    test2_tenant  = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.add_allowed_test_domain()
        cls.setUpTestData()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print('run setUpTestData')

        cls.public_tenant = Tenant.create_tenant('Public')
        cls.test_tenant   = Tenant.create_tenant('Test')
        cls.test2_tenant  = Tenant.create_tenant('Test2')

        connection.set_tenant(cls.public_tenant)
```

I read that setUpTestData() is supposed to run before each test case (if subclassed from django.test.testcase), but it wasn't running in my case.  I had to put cls.setUpTestData() in setUpClass() to get it to run.

This is a stripped-down example of one of my tests...

```py
class TenantModelTests(TenantTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        super(TenantModelTests, self).setUp()

    def test_check_public_tenant(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.public_tenant, Tenant)

        self.assertEqual(self.public_tenant.name, 'Public', 'Public tenant name is not "Public".')
        self.assertEqual(self.public_tenant.subdomain, '', 'Public tenant subdomain is not blank.')
        self.assertEqual(self.public_tenant.schema_name, 'public', 'Public tenant schema_name is not "public".')

    def test_check_private_tenants(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.test_tenant, Tenant)

        self.assertEqual(self.test_tenant.name, 'Test', 'Test tenant name is not "Test".')
        self.assertEqual(self.test_tenant.subdomain, 'test', 'Test tenant subdomain is not "test".')
        self.assertEqual(self.test_tenant.schema_name, 'test', 'Test tenant schema_name is not "test".')
```

When I run this with two test files in two different apps, I see "run setUpTestData" twice - and, of course, I see the "already exist" exceptions.  So where should I put code that should run once at the beginning of the entire test run?

Comment: Did you find out in the mean time?

Comment: @Soren, I/we put the unittesting part of our project on hold not long after I posted this question. I know that's not ideal for development, but we had to make some tough choices re: our timeframe. At this point (so many months later), I can't recall if I found a work-around or not. If I did, I'm guessing it probably wasn't the "Django way". Sorry I can't be of more specific help.

Answer (score 3):

`setUpTestData` is called is once for TestCase.
In case databases does not support transactions, setUpTestData will be called before each test run.

Change your `setUpClass` and don't call `setUpTestData` directly. Try to user super()

```py
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.add_allowed_test_domain()
    super(TenantTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```

Ref:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#testcase
`Note that if the tests are run on a database with no transaction support (for instance, MySQL with the MyISAM engine), setUpTestData() will be called before each test, negating the speed benefits.`

Comment: @`K_K` - Thanks for that.  It solved the issue of setUpTestData() not being called automagically, but the real question of my post was the one at the end:

Where should I put code that should run once at the beginning of the entire test run?

Comment: My question too.